# Why am I getting the error 58031 while connecting to DB2 within SSIS package?

Tags: c#, ssis

Hi I am trying connect to DB2 but it is giving an error as

> ```
> [UDB Source [1]] Error: IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Exception: ERROR [58031] [IBM]
> SQL1031N  The database directory cannot be found on the indicated file
> system.  SQLSTATE=58031
> ```

It is an SSIS package where I am using a script component to connect to DB2.but it is not openning the connection.

My piece of code is

```
string dbName = "GRTST";
string uid = "c001";
string pwd = "winter1";

DB2Connection conn = new DB2Connection();
conn.ConnectionString = "DataBase=" + dbName + ";" + "Uid=" + uid + ";" +"Pwd="+ pwd + ";";

conn.Open();
```

The error description is

> [UDB Source [1]] Error: IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Exception: ERROR [58031] [IBM] SQL1031N  The database directory cannot be found on the
>   indicated file system.  SQLSTATE=58031
>
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.HandleUserException(Exception
>   e)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.PrimeOutput(Int32
>   outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] buffers)
>          at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostPrimeOutput(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100
>   wrapper, Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, IDTSBuffer100[] buffers,
>   IntPtr ppBufferWirePacket)

Please provide me your valuable suggestion so that I can move forward.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue in question:

The issue in the question is that you have not specified the server to which you would like to connect in the connection string. Following link shows how to formulate a DB2 connection string:

[Connection strings for IBM DB2](http://www.connectionstrings.com/ibm-db2)

#### Appropriate way to connect to databases within SSIS:

Having said that, what you are trying to do in the question is **not** an appropriate way to connect to a database. You should create a data source at the SSIS project level or a connection manager within the SSIS package to connect to your DB2 data source. Following links describe how to connect to a DB2 data source using `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for DB2`.

[Connecting to DB2 using SSIS](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/PatrickLeBlanc/ssis/700/connecting-to-db2-using-ssis)

[Connecting to DB2 from SSIS - Another link](http://thirteendaysaweek.com/2010/05/16/connecting-to-db2-from-ssis/)

Also, here is the MSDN documentation on how to add connection managers

[How to: Add or Delete a Connection Manager in a Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140237%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)